# Is this site a good place to share your music for others to comment on

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if it would be appropriate to share say an mp3 of improvisation or some composition on a pdf or if this is not that kind of site?

Answer (score 5):

No, the main problem with that sort of post is that it couldn't meet our question requirements... This is, after all, a Question and Answer site, not a discussion forum or music sharing site.

Various folks share music (their own or favourite pieces) in chat, which may serve your needs.

Answer (score 2):

As Doktor Mayhem says, posting your work as part of a general *'what do you think of this? comments please!*' request on the main site doesn't really work here if there's no specific question about music being asked.

However, I do think it would be great if we could share more music, and for now I think it's fine do to so in [the main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room). I'm not sure how many comments you'll get (the chat room is pretty quiet), but the more people we have sharing music in there, the noisier it will be...

Comment: Yes, it would be too subjective.